# Fetching token metadata from token URI

Tags: tokens, dapps, dapp-development, nft, erc-1155

Is there an efficient way to get the metadatas of a list of token uri's? Like, what if I have a list of 50 token Uris, would the only way be to send a different get request to each url?

Comment: Hi! Can you give us more details, such as if this is being done from a smart contract or if not, what language you are using? Have you encountered a particular difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

URIs can be hosted anywhere, so by the definition, you need to create new HTTPS connection to every server. However you can use HTTP 1.1 keep-alive if the server supports it, so it will reuse the same underlying TCP/IP connection.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I can't really understand. Right now I'm using axios to fetch some url's and get back the metadatas, but I've gotten the 429 'too many requests' error too. Will this solve that problem? thanks.

Comment: 497 too many requests can be only solved by slowing down your requests.